# Basic D3.js: create or update element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Basic D3.js question, getting to grips with the syntax!

I'm using D3 and I want to **create** an axis if it doesn't exist, or **update** it with a transition if it does already exist.

My current code is below, but this code re-creates the axis each time - it doesn't transition. How can I change it to transition?

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(4).tickSize(6, 3, 0);

updateGraphAndAxes(initialdata);

$('#button').click(function() { 
  updateGraphAndAxes(newdata);
});

function updateGraphAndAxes(newdata) { 
  // update x.domain here using newdata, then... 
  svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(xAxis);
}
```

Comment: The answer to one of my questions might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529389/d3-attaching-data-to-an-axis-for-rescaling/11530872#comment15284589_11530872

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this example](http://natescodevault.com/js/line/).  The approach is like this:

```
var xAxisGroup = null;

function updateGraphAndAxes(newdata) { 

    var t = null;

    t = svg.transition().duration(1000);        // Set up transition

    // update x.domain using newdata... 

    if (!xAxisGroup) {
        xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "xTick")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);           
    } else {
        t.select('.xTick').call(xAxis);     // Call xAxis on transition
    }
}
```