# Normalize x values and log y values in d3.js

Tags: node.js, d3.js

I am using Scatter plot to visualize data http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118. I have more than 2 graphs on a page. I want to keep two options where an user can select 
 1. Normalize button: Values at x-axes will get normalized and new graphs are plotted.
 2. log y button: Values at y axes are changed to log y and new graphs are built on the same page accordingly.

How to do this d3.js?

Also I am plotting this using Nodejs, Express and d3.js.

Till now I have built the graphs. These are the options to increase interactivity.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best is to define two different scales:

```
var yNormal = d3.scale.linear() ...
```

and

```
var yLog = d3.scale.log() ....
```

and on button click redraw the circles using the other scale:

```
//in button event handler
if( /* log */) {
   svg.selectAll(".dot").attr('cy', function() { return yLog(d.yourDataField); }
}
else {
   svg.selectAll(".dot").attr('cy', function() { return yNorm(d.yourDataField); }
}
```

You can also use transition to animate the redraw like this:

```
svg.selectAll(".dot").transition().duration(500).attr('cy', function() { return yLog(d.yourDataField); }
```

You can also animate the rescaling of the axis using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529389/d3-attaching-data-to-an-axis-for-rescaling) method.

You can apply the same to X axis as well.